# What's the difference between "loving" a song and clicking a song's heart in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I'm finally experimenting with an iTunes Music subscription, hoping to find music I like based on what I already like.

iTunes seems to have two ways to express my opinion on a song I'm listening to in iTunes Music:

- I can select a song and, two-finger click on is and select either "Love" or "Disklike".

  [image]
- Separately, I can hover to the left of the song and a heart outline heart will appear, and I can click this, which fills the heart in with red. Clicking again toggles it back.

  [image]

These two actions seem to be independent. "Loving" a song doesn't turn the heart on, turning the heart on doesn't "love" a song.

What do these two things indicate? Which one, if either, will make it more likely that iTunes Music will suggest songs that I might like?

Answer (score 2):

It's the same thing. Unfortunately there appears to be a bug where the UI doesn't update one when you select the other, but it's stored the same and will appear the same next time iTunes refreshes that playlist/etc.

Comment: How does one get iTunes to refresh the play list? I went elsewhere in the interface and returned to the playlist, as well as quit iTunes and went back to the playlist. My "loves" were retained, but not the hearts.

Comment: @Chuck I've just tried it and I had to quit iTunes completely and relaunch it. It's definitely a recent bug which should mean it'll be fixed soon.